# Flutter camera plugin stream live video and audio (video call)

Tags: flutter, android-camera

I want to use the 'camera' plugin in flutter to create a live p2p video call. I read about it and I find out that there is a listener named '`startImageStream`'. This listener returns an image each time an image prepared (`CameraImage`) so I decide to use a UDP socket to transfer each image to other client, so I created a video call app here !!! But I have some questions about it:

- how to play the transferred '`CameraImage`' in other client app !!! What even I have to transter throw UDP !? Where is each image buffer (data for transfer to other client app) ?
- What about Audio !? I have to use another plugin to capture and send audio throw UDP separately ?